# How do i create a large "empty" space between 2 horizontal tables

Tags: html, css

im creating a table for my Power Apps Project and i need a foundation so i can add the entries later on.

I want to create a excel-like table with entries. I am using a template from work loking like the first picture[image: Excel Template]

With the help of a friend i got a solid html code looking like this:[image: HTML Progress]

When comparing the pictures, you can see a space between each table. How can i archieve that?

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    <!--Information für den Browser um welches Dokument es sich handelt-->
<html lang="de">    <!--//zuordnung der Sprache-->

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">    <!--ä, ü, ö möglich-->
   <title>Überschrift</title>    <!--Tab-Überschrift-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    <!--responsive-->

<style type="text/css">   
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid #054F9D;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    max-width: 12rem;
    min-width: 12rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.grey {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    min-width: 5rem;
    max-width: 5rem;
}

p {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2rem;
}

@media print {
    .pagebreak {page-break-before: always;} /*Seitenumbruch*/
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Überschrift</h1>

<!--Kundendaten-->
<div><p>Bereich</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<!--Fahrzeugdaten-->
<div><p>Bereich2</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>fevjvjjvjvjdfvjfvjfvjfjvjfdvjfdjvjfdjvfd</td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>vfdjvjvjfjvfjvjvjfdvjfdjvfjdvjfdvjfdjvdj</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried a new html with display; inline-block. However it only created a small space and i want them to be a bit larger. Didnt know how to achieve this

Comment: you can wrap the tables in a div and give make it flex with justify-content space between, then the gap will depend on the size of the tables and the size of the page.  The code  you've provided has your tables stacking - you need to make a [mcve] of what you currently have otherwise it looks like you haven't attempted anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the table into separate tables and then add space, using flexbox for example:

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #054F9D;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  max-width: 12rem;
  min-width: 12rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.grey {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 5rem;
  max-width: 5rem;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

@media print {
  .pagebreak {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  /*Seitenumbruch*/
}

div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>vfdjvjvjfjvfjvjvjfdvjfdjvfjdvjfdvjfdjvdj</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>vfdjvjvjfjvfjvjvjfdvjfdjvfjdvjfdvjfdjvdj</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separator cell to your tables like this:

```css
.separator {
  border: none;
  border-top-style : hidden;
  border-bottom-style : hidden;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="separator"></td>
    <td class="grey">Inhalt</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

This is the result:
[image]